# Phantomjs can't find the javascript file

Tags: javascript, windows, phantomjs

I am new to Phantomjs I just downloaded its version for Windows.
I opened the **bin** folder and run the command in **phantomjs.exe**:

```
phantomjs hello.js
```

But it gives me the error : ***Expected an identifier bu found "hello" instead***

Then I run this command:

```
hello.js
```

I get this error : ***Can't find variable hello***

I have following codes in my hello.js

```
console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.exit();
```

I have **hello.js and phantomjs.exe in same folder**,but it can't find the js file. I searhed over web but could not find an appropiate solution.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My mistake was trying to execute commands **by opening the phantomjs.exe in bin** folder. I opened **windows cmd** and go to the **path of phantomjs.exe** and this command worked:

```
phantomjs hello.js
```

***So don't try to run commands on phantomjs.exe, open your cmd instead***

Answer (score 0):

I've also failed into same situation and spend unnecessary time to make it work, So I am adding step by step procedure to run your first phantomjs program on windows.

Step 1: Download phantomjs ( [windows version](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)  )

Step 2: unzip the downloaded file.

Step 3: copy the path to phantomjs's bin folder, and set it in environment variable

Step 4: go to your work_folder , create hello.js

Step 5: open cmd , go to your work_folder and run your hello.js using following command

```
phantomjs hello.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps, if you find this error `"Can't open hello.js"`

1. Assume you have downloaded and installed in this following path `C:\PhantomJs`
2. Open your cmd prompt. Just type go to phantom js folder `C:\>cd phantomjs`
3. Just type `C:\PhantomJs>PhantomJs hello.js` you should be able to see the output as `hello world`

[image]